# How can I access textbox properties in a custom validator?

Tags: asp.net, validation, textbox, custom-server-controls

I want to build a custom validator control that inherits from BaseValidator.  It will only be used on textboxes in my asp.net application.  How can I get access to the textbox itself (read properties of the textbox) within the custom validator?

Here is what I have in my EvaluateIsValid function:

```
 Dim t As TextBox = CType(Page.FindControl(Me.ControlToValidate), TextBox)
 Return t.Text.Length <= t.MaxLength
```

It can't seem to find the control, so it breaks with a null reference exception.  Can I do this another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the textbox:

Dim t As TextBox = CType(Me.FindControl(Me.ControlToValidate), TextBox)

Comment: Me.FindControl did it.  I don't know why - I would think that b/c the textbox is not in the naming container of the validator it would not work, but it did.  thanks!